# Recommended number of ssytems under an ISSO

Tags: risk-management, risk, business-risk

Is there an optimum number of systems an ISSO should be responsible for?  I realize system size and complexity come into play but assuming most are large and of moderate risk, etc. is there a number that can be consideered a norm?  We have ISSOs who have  8 or 9 high value systems and need justification from a reliable source of any norm or standard to ensure maximum security and reasonable work load.  Thanks.